# shared test classes in multimdule android project

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, clean-architecture

I have an app developed in clean architecture with multiple modules. consider below package structure.

```
app
  src 
   |--> main 
   |--> test
          |--> test classes that access shared test classes from common-test like mainCoroutineRue
data
   src 
    |--> main
    |--> test
          |--> test classes that access shared test classes from common-test like FakeDispatcher

common-test
   src
    |--> main
           |--> MainCorotineRule
           |--> FakeDispatcher
    |--> test
```

Here are the gradle files code:

app:

```
dependencies{
    testImplementation project(':common-test')
}
```

data :

```
plugins{
id 'java-library'
id 'kotlin'
}
dependencies{
testImplemenation project(path:':common-test',configuration:'default')
}
```

common-test:

```
plugins{
id 'com.android.library'
id 'kotlin-android'
}

dependecies{
 implementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:1.1.1"
//test classes 
//implementation junit
//impementation coroutine-test
//mockk
}
```

Now the problem is that i am successfully able to access classes like MainCoroutineRule inside apps test classes but i am not able to access classes(i.e. FakeDispatcher) from common-test into test folder of data module while i run the test though compile time it imports the right class from common-test.
the error it throws is "unresolved reference"
Please let know what is the miss ?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience I haven’t been able to successfully create an aar (android library) for testing purposes which might be your main issue here. There is a one way compatibility between android libraries (aar) vs java libraries (jar). You can include jars into an aar but you can't do it the other way around.

If you don't need an aar for your tests (basically you don't need anything related to the android resources), I would suggest you change the testing library to the java plugin. If you need references to the Android classes you can always import the sources for android similar to what robolectric does [here](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/master/robolectric/build.gradle#L44)

Comment: I have edited my question . So Basically i need common-test as android lib as i need some android related base testing class and thier libs like "android.arch.core:core-testing:1.1.1"

Comment: Bit of an update then. You are right, looking at the core-testing lib it is an aar, so what I would suggest is that you split your test module into common-test & android-test and consume common from android and including android specific code and keeping the java only code separate and reusable by all modules